# "__git ps1: command not found" from bashrc

Tags: bash, git

When I try and go to the .ssh directory with cd ~/.ssh it correctly navigates to that directory but I get a __git ps1: command not found. Not sure why this is happening and how to resolve the issue.

here is my bashrc file

```
#Git tab completion
source ~/git-completion.bash
# Show branch in status line
PS1='[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your prompt contains the `__git_ps1` function call, but it isn't defined.  Newer versions of the git-completion file define this function but it's not in your copy.  EG, on Fedora, its defined in `/etc/bash_completion.d/git`

Comment: I am pretty much a noob, so what would I do prevent this error. Because the PS1 line I think helps me show branch in status line. I am not sure what to do?

Comment: It's ok to be a noob, it's how we all start :-)  What linux (I assume) distribution are you using?

Comment: oh, I am using mac actually. I just tried to follow instructions from hereto define ps1 http://effectif.com/git/config but it didn't work.

Comment: Ah.  I don't have a running mac in front of me to see if there is a file on it that defines __git_ps1, so lets do this instead:  Grab: http://capturedonearth.com/temp/git-completion.bash and use that file instead of the one you're using now and I suspect your problem will go away.